# How can I get the IP of the interface getaddrinfo() (addrinfo) uses for connect()

Tags: c++, windows, networking, ip, winsock2

I need to be able to verify my app is using the right interface and IMO the best way to do that is to know the IP of the interface it's trying to use.

```
struct addrinfo                 *result = NULL,
                                *ptr = NULL,
                                hints;
```

`getaddrinfo(sServer.c_str(), DEFAULT_PORT, &hints, &result);`

```
ptr=result;

iResult = SOCKET_ERROR;

int iTries = 0;
while (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR && iTries <= 5)
{
    // Create a SOCKET for connecting to server
    m_ConnectSocket = socket(ptr->ai_family, ptr->ai_socktype, ptr->ai_protocol);

    // Connect to server.
    iResult = connect( m_ConnectSocket, ptr->ai_addr, (int)ptr->ai_addrlen);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        closesocket(m_ConnectSocket);
        m_ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;

        ptr = result->ai_next;
    }

    iTries++;
}
```

I'm guessing I need to get it out of `ptr` or `result` but I have no idea how.

---

Update:

I added some `getsockname()` code which as far as I can tell is just fabricating random IP's. I have no idea where they are coming from:

```
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        closesocket(m_ConnectSocket);
        m_ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;

        ptr = result->ai_next;
    }
    else
    {
        SOCKADDR_IN ClientSocketInterface;

        getsockname(m_ConnectSocket, (SOCKADDR*)&ClientSocketInterface, (int*)sizeof(ClientSocketInterface));

        string sIP = inet_ntoa(ClientSocketInterface.sin_addr);
    }
```

I got `44.x.x.x`, `200.x.x.x`, `60.x.x.x` IP's in the first three tests so something isn't quite right. I can verify that when it is a valid socket, I am able to send/receive between `localhost`.

Comment: Your last parameter to `getsockname()` is wrong. You need to assign the `sizeof()` value to a real `int` variable and then pass a pointer to that variable to `getsockname()` (which can modify the value, so it needs to be a real variable), do not simply type-cast the `sizeof()` value directly to a pointer.  And you are not doing any error handling on `getsockname()`'s return value, either. Don't call `inet_ntoa()` if `getsockname()` fails, the data will be garbage.

Comment: Also, you did not show what values you are populating the `hints` variable with when calling `getaddrinfo()`. If it returns an IPv6 address and you create an IPv6 socket, your use of a `sockaddr_in` variable will not work, you need to use `sockaddr_in6` or better `sockaddr_storage` instead. And `inet_ntoa()` only works with IPv4, not IPv6, so you would need to use `inet_ntop()` or equivalent instead.

Comment: Also, `getaddrinfo()` can return multiple IP addresses for a given host, so you should be looping through the entire `addrinfo` chain.  If one address fails, try the next one, and so on until one succeeds or the chain is exhausted.  THEN retry the entire chain again if desired, repeating as needed.

Comment: Thanks, I figured out the same but if you write an answer I'll accept yours instead. Good to know about IPv6 but thankfully this is entirely local and I won't have to deal with that. The while loop does do the looping for trying all the addresses so far as I know.

Comment: The `while` loop you have shown DOES NOT account for multiple IP addreses in the `addrinfo` chain. And if you want to limit your code to IPv4, just make sure you specify `AF_INET` in the `hints` and not `AF_INET6` or `AF_UNSPEC`.

Comment: Ah, good to know. I was using `AF_UNSPEC`.

Comment: Read the [`getaddrinfo()` documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738520.aspx): "*A value of `AF_UNSPEC` for `ai_family` indicates the caller will accept any protocol family. This value can be used to **return both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses** for the host name pointed to by the `pNodeName` parameter*", so you have to pay attention to the actual `ai_family` value you are passing to `socket()`, it could be either `AF_INET` or `AF_INET6`, which then affects all uses of `sockaddr_XXX` structures on that socket.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Well that's news to me. The first one has always been failing so I thought it was looping and selecting the next one which worked. This is a separate question but what am I missing that actually loops to the next potential address?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103764/discussion-between-remy-lebeau-and-enigma).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This did the trick:

```
SOCKADDR_IN ClientSocketInterface;
memset(&ClientSocketInterface, 0, sizeof(ClientSocketInterface));
int iNlen = sizeof(ClientSocketInterface);

getsockname(m_ConnectSocket, (SOCKADDR*)&ClientSocketInterface, &iNlen);

string sIP = inet_ntoa(ClientSocketInterface.sin_addr);
STrace = String::Format("Client IP: [{0}:{1}]", gcnew String(sIP.c_str()), htons(ClientSocketInterface.sin_port));
Trace(STrace, TRACE_INFO);
```

Answer (score 1):

After connecting, call `getsockname()` to find out the address of the local side of the socket (`getpeername` for the remote side).

You can also call `bind()` before `connect()` to select a particular local address... pass zero as the port number if you want the OS to select a free ephemeral port as it does when you don't call bind at all.

Comment: An example of the usage of `getsockname()` would also be helpful.